# Jmeter: Additional requests when I run load test via command line

Tags: jmeter, load

I have a load test and run it via command line. When I got result, I see that it make additional request but they are absent in load test.

I have attached result that generated (Just in case my command line:

```
jmeter -n -t c:\Load\Average\Login.jmx -l c:\Load\Average\JmeterResult\%timestamp%\AverageResult.jtl -e -o c:\Load\Average\AverageResult\%timestamp%\
```

)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/od0CO.png)

Please look at the screenshot. I marked additional request and total request. It is 4800 but should 2400

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The "additional" requests can originate from:

1. [Redirects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)
2. [Embedded resources downloads](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/web-testing-jmeter)

If you want to "get rid" of them you can add the following stanza:

```
-Jjmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter="^(Login-browser|Send request to login)(-success|-failure)?$"
```

and the "child" sample results will be filtered out (you will still have 4800 as the final result but these `Login-browser-0` and friends will be hidden.

Comment: Thank you Dmitri! Yeah you are right. It is redirected URLs. Are there ways to ignore them in results? I mean that I want to have the same result like I do manually via Jmeter GUI namely 2400 instead of 4800. If I look at the Summary Report in GUI I see 2400 request.